# Ways to visualize a point on a scale on a web page

Tags: javascript, visualization, gauge

I am looking for recommendations to visualize points on a scale on a web page. A [Gauge type of representation](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html), as provided by Google, or [a bullet chart as provided by Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/bullet.html) seem to be good candidates. But perhaps there's more. (Or perhaps there are some libraries that do something similar that I haven't seen yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at some of the things you can do with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [g.Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).  It is a great pure JS library that lets you do the charts you suggest and a lot more.  The interaction you can add with it is pretty interesting.

Comment: That's what I eventually ended up doing. You're right. Good stuff.